# PHP/MySQL Check Login Details

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

I have the code below that should check the login details when a form is submitted:

```
<html><body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","will","blahblah");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("blahblah", $con);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users  WHERE  pass =md5('$password') AND user = $username)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query2)==1) {
$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)
VALUES
('". mysql_escape_string($_POST['link']) ."','". mysql_escape_string($_POST['notes']) ."','". mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']) ."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 link added";

mysql_close($con)
}
else {
echo "Username or password was not correct, please try again";
}
?>
</body></html>
```

But I get an error which says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_STRING in
>   /data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/processpopup.php
>   on line 13

Line 13 is this line: `$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)`

The form code is:

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="processpopup.php">
<label>Username
<span class="small">Enter Your Username</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<label>Password
<span class="small">Enter Your Password</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" />

<label>Link
<span class="small">Paste Your Link</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="link" id="link" />

<label>Notes
<span class="small">Add Some Notes</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="notes" id="notes" />

<button type="submit"></button>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
</div>
```

I honestly have no idea what is happening. Thanks!

Comment: Will Evans, please stop spamming questions. Why not buy a good old book on PHP and read it. The error sais that you forgot an ' or " somewhere to terminate a string.

Comment: You should use an editor with syntax highlighting.

Comment: No need to downvote just because it's a newbie question? Hehe, even though we could probably mark the SO syntax highlighter as to have answered the question correctly.

Comment: @Znarkus: Please revoke your upvote. He posted already 11 pretty low quality questions today. It's not going to get better by encouraging him.

Comment: Guys, I've only just started I need help.... if you are willing to help then I'm getting the error unknown column 'john' in where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an ending quote for

```
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users  WHERE  pass =md5('$password') AND user = $username)or die(mysql_error());
```

it should be

```
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users  WHERE  pass =md5('$password') AND user = $username")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I get unknown colum 'john' in where clause

Comment: You are not quoting most of your strings in the query. `user = '$username'`

Comment: I have quoted them and I am getting an incorrect password or username when I create it a few seconds before...

Answer (score 0):

Look a couple of lines above that:

$query2=mysql_query("

There is no ending "

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","will","blahblah");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("blahblah", $con);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users  WHERE  pass = '".md5('$password')."' AND user = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query2)==1) {
$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes, username)
VALUES
('". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']) ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']) ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) ."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 link added";

mysql_close($con)
}
else {
echo "Username or password was not correct, please try again";
}
?>
</body></html>
```

You forgot to close the string on line 11, so it bugged out

-edit- added single quotes around md5 string

-edit2- per comment, didnt check to see you didnt have proper single quotes everywhere.  Fixed, as well as sanitized all data properly

Comment: getting an error even if the password is right... the signup form to set the password is this: function addNewUser($username, $password){
   global $connection;
   $password1 = md5($password);
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
   return mysql_query($q, $connection);

Comment: Seems it is something not being entered right.  May want to check and see if there is even an entry in your db.

Comment: There are entries for the user and an md5 password. They are in the right columns. There are no entries into the links table because it says the password or username is wrong so it didn't get to that...

Comment: There is something wrong with the actual query you posted if I use: $query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users  WHERE  pass =md5('$password') AND user = '$username'")or die(mysql_error()); it works please could you post a fixed one with your security method.

Comment: You have to make sure you mysql_real_escape_string the username or it will have bugs.  where you have `$username = $_POST['username']`, make it `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);`